# create comments for nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, comments, nested-routes

I'm trying to make a blog which has users, posts and comments. Each user can have many posts and many comments similarly each post can have many comments. I have successfully made the user and post sections but am having difficulty creating comments and then displaying them.

code:

routes.rb :

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

user.rb :

```
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

post.rb :

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

comment.rb :

```
belongs_to :post, :user
```

I'm creating and displaying comments in the post's view itself so..

posts_controller.rb :

```
def show
  @user = current_user
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

view/posts/show.html.erb :

```
<p><strong>Title:</strong><%= @post.title %></p>

<p><strong>Text:</strong><%= @post.text %></p>


<% if @user.posts.comments.empty? %>
  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <%= render @posts.comments %>
<% end %>


<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render "comments/form" %>

<%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_user_post_path(@user.id,@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back to Posts',  user_posts_path(@user.id) %>
```

comments_controller.rb :

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
@user = current_user
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @user.posts.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to user_post_path(@user.id,@post)
  end

  def destroy
@user = current_user
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @user.posts.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to user_post_path(@user.id,@post)
  end
end
```

And the partials are:

views/comments/_form.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for([@user,@post,@comment]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= @user.email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I think my form_for is not right here but I'm new to rails and I've also tried form_for(@user,@post,@post.comments.build) but that didn't work either.. Anyways here's another partial:

views/comments/_comment.html.erb:

```
<p><strong>Commenter:</strong><%= @user.email %></p>

<p><strong>Comment:</strong><%= comment.body %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

Again here I'm having trouble with link to...any suggestions would be great.

Comment: run rake routes and paste the output on gist or pastie.org

Comment: @rmagnum2002 here's the list of rake routes [link](http://pastie.org/8246607)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer here it is:

posts_controller:

```
def show
  @user = current_user
  @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<p><strong>Title:</strong><%= @post.title %></p>

<p><strong>Text:</strong><%= @post.text %></p>


<% if !@post.comments.empty? %>
  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <%= render @comment %>
<% end %>


<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render "comments/form" %>

<%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_user_post_path(@user.id,@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back to Posts',  user_posts_path(@user.id) %>
```

comments_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @post = @user.posts.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
  redirect_to user_post_path(@user.id,@post)
end
```

comment's partial

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for([@user,@post,@comment]) do |f| %>
<p><%= @user.email %></p>
<p><%= f.label :body %><br />
<%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to make a blog which has users , posts and comments, I see some differences between what you did and what I did it before when I was creating a blog also. I will tell you what I did (by editing the code of the files you posted in your question) then try it if it works with you :)

1- routes.rb make it like this

```
resources :users
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

2- user.rb is fine no need to be modified

3- post.rb also is fine

4- comments.rb

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

5- posts_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
```

6- view/posts/show.html.erb ( this view should make you able to see the post and the comments and a box for the new comments, and a link to edit post and a link to the posts index )

```
<p><strong>Title:</strong><%= @post.title %></p>

<p><strong>Text:</strong><%= @post.text %></p>

  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <%= render @posts.comments %>


<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render "comments/form" %>

<%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back to Posts',  posts_path %>
```

7- comments_controller.rb ( don't forget to add the destroy method again )

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_post
  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: "Added comment."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def load_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:article_id])
  end
end
```

8- views/comments/_form.html.erb (just try to make it first in a simple way)

```
<%= form_for([@post,@comment]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

9- views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<p><strong>Commenter:</strong><%= comment.user.email %></p>

<p><strong>Comment:</strong><%= comment.body %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

I hope this work with you as it works with me, try it and let me know how it goes with you, i got my blog work from [the before code for revised episode 229](https://github.com/railscasts/229-polling-for-changes-revised/tree/master/blog-before).

Comment: the thing is i don't have any problem when comments are nested once..it's when they are double nested that i'm having problem

Comment: when i try to show posts it shows undefined method `comments' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x61f3338> and if i remove <% if @user.posts.comments.empty? %>
  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <%= render @posts.comments %>
<% end %> it shows undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: i need to have posts inside users as a user can have many posts and if a user gets deleted or something then all its posts are also deleted :)

Comment: did not try it yet but I will and tell you if it done with me, have you tried my answer ?

Comment: sorry i didn't try it. Earlier i had made something similar to your code where posts and comments were nested and users were separate and that worked fine..so i know it will work but now the requirements were changed so i had to change the code :)

Comment: you can't test it with `<% if @user.posts.comments.empty? %>` it should be `<% if @post.comments.empty? %>` or `<% if @user.posts.find(params[:post_id]).comments.empty? %>`. You should check if any comments for one post not for all

Comment: @rmagnum2002 yeah i got it..sorry i forgot to update it here. I'll post the answer